# Alternate Solution to Passing Parameter by Reference in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to implement the insert-at-head functionality of a linked list, and would like to return a void* pointer to the newly inserted node via passing by reference. I unfortunately cannot change the parameters. This is my relevant code:

```
typedef struct List_t_def{
 spinlock_t * lock_counter;
 unsigned int key;
 struct List_t_def *next;
}list_t;

typedef volatile unsigned int spinlock_t;//basic lock

void List_Insert(list_t *list, void *element, unsigned int key) {  
  list_t * list_new = (list_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
  spinlock_t * lock_temp = (spinlock_t*)malloc(sizeof(spinlock_t));
  list_new->lock_counter = lock_temp;

  spinlock_acquire(list->lock_counter);
  list_new->key = key;    //inserting the new created node as the first one (head of the linked list)
  list_new->next = list->next;
  list_new->lock_counter = list->lock_counter;    

  list->next = list_new;

  element = (void*)list_new; 

  spinlock_release(list->lock_counter);

  return;
}
```

I'm trying to set `element` to the start of the newly inserted node, but when it returns, `element` doesn't change its previous value. Any suggestions or help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to pass in element as a void**

Comment: I can't change the parameters of the function.

Comment: Well, then I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Might help to show people the code that calls that function.

Comment: list->next = list_new basically assigning to the "list" input argument. Caller can make use of this as "list" memory has provided by calling function. Does it make sense for your program?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know you can't change the parameters but if you can change the implementation and and the caller of this function you *could* do it!

The horrible(ly nice) thing about C is that you can cast anything to anything you want. So even though you can't change the function signature to take a void** you can still pass one anyway. Example:

```
char *element = (char *)malloc(0xDEADBEEF);
List_Insert(list, (void*)&element, key);
```

Inside the function, you can cast it back to a void**:

```
void List_Insert(list_t *list, void *element, unsigned int key) {
    void **e = (void **)element;

    /* do stuff */

    *e = (void *)list_new;
}
```

Voila! BTW, this is horrible and not intuitive for the caller. I hope this is not production code :)

Answer (score 0):

As already was suggested if you can't modify function prototype, you can still use your `void*` parameter to pass any kind of pointer into the function, including pointer-to-pointer to return your new element.

Let me just refine the code to show less abstract example for this usage:

```
void List_Insert_Caller() {
    // ...
    list_t *new_element;
    List_Insert(list, &new_element, key);
    // new_element now points to newly created list_t element
}

void List_Insert(list_t *list, void *new_element_ptr_ptr, unsigned int key) {
    // ...
    list_t **new_element = (list_t **)new_element_ptr_ptr;
    // ...
    *new_element = list_new;
}
```